# HTTP return error 500 on Meteor production app, but 200 on localhost

Tags: http, meteor

I'm starting to use MeteorJs since today, and I'm trying to use HTTP package to load an external content.

This is my server side code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    makeRequest: function (url) {
      return HTTP.call("GET", url);
    }
  });
}
```

And Client side, I try to make 2 requests: one directly from client, and the other one from the server method:

```
var url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/6133/pg6133.txt";

// Make a request from the client
Meteor.http.call("GET", url, function(err, result) { 
  console.log("-- CLIENT SIDE --");
  console.log("err : ", err);
  console.log("result : ", result);
});

// Make a request from server 
Meteor.call('makeRequest', url, function(err, result) {
  console.log("-- SERVER SIDE --");
  console.log("err : ", err);
  console.log("result : ", result);
});
```

On localhost, the server side work fine. But on the server I got:

[image]

**Question #1:** How can I easy debug the server ?

**Question #2:** For this URL (http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/6133/pg6133.txt) I have a redirection the first time you call the server to a new URL (http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/6133?msg=welcome_stranger). This is a possible cause for the error, but how can I handle that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to debug server side is to use :

`meteor logs <site>`